# Android Studio 2.3.2 doesn't open Android *.xml layout files

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Install the latest Android Studio 2.3.2, I'm not able to open my Android layout xml-Files in IntelliJ IDEA anymore. Other resources like styles,menus and preferences work.

Things Tried out:
a)Build -> Clean Project and then Build -> Rebuild Project.
b)Invalidate Cache and Restart

[image]

```
Log File.================================================
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.3.2  Build #AI-162.3934792 
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 7 
2017-06-05 10:02:47,957 [2188972]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: GotoDeclaration 
2017-06-05 10:02:48,895 [2189910]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor$ASTTreeGuide.getFirstChild(RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor$ASTTreeGuide.getFirstChild(RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.next(WalkingState.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.walkChildren(WalkingState.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.elementStarted(WalkingState.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.visitNode(RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.java:85)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.visitComposite(RecursiveTreeElementWalkingVisitor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.AstBufferUtil$BufferVisitor.visitComposite(AstBufferUtil.java:114)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.acceptTree(CompositeElement.java:160)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.AstBufferUtil.toBuffer(AstBufferUtil.java:40)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.AstBufferUtil.toBuffer(AstBufferUtil.java:35)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.textToCharArray(CompositeElement.java:313)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.getText(CompositeElement.java:265)
    at com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTDelegatePsiElement.getText(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:147)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getReferenceText(GradleDslReference.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Invalidate cache and restart` ?

Comment: Yes Tired many times "Invalidate cache and restart"

Comment: I have one more idea that maybe you have added a buggy library

Comment: Same project working on my colleague Machine but he is running AS 2.2.3 (version older ) ,when you say library you mean application dependency or a AS plugin

Comment: I always backUp my projects after every progress, then when stuff like this happened, I jump into my previous project, then I copy my progressed project files one by one.

Comment: I meant any library, but specially external ones

Comment: @Sam did you fix this issue? It's happening to me since AS 2.3 (updated to 2.3.3 now and it's still broken). Not only when opening layouts, but also for example when I click File -> Project Structure. Does that one work for you?

Comment: @quezak please try one of the options in the answer. i was able to get it work, same issues i faced project structure diaalog and layout not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can try few options to fix this

01) download 2.3 version of the IDE and install separately. create a new project and copy your project files (java/resources) to the new project.

you may receive a prompt to also update Gradle to the latest available version. You can choose to accept the update or manually specify a version based on your project's build requirements.

02)check out the project to new location and import it again to AS

03) delete your .idea/-*.iml files/folder and restart the AS

04) Try upgrading the gradle version to latest and Android gradle plugin to latest

You can specify the Android plugin for Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or the top-level build.gradle file. The plugin version applies to all modules built in that Android Studio project. The following example sets the Android plugin for Gradle to version 2.3.3 from the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  }
}
```

You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file. The following example sets the Gradle version to 3.3 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Tried 2) and 3), but nothing changed. 1) is too much for me, because it's a big, complicated project, which probably is the cause here... Thanks for writing anyway.